# Open External Password Protected Database with Automation in Access Runtime Version

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to open an external password protected database in separate window. I have tried follwoing code (shared by Isladogs from MendipDataSystems on some forum):

```
Public Function RunExternalDatabase() As Boolean
    
    Dim app As Access.Application, strPath As String
    
    'Start a new MSAccess application
    Set app = New Access.Application
    
    'Open the remote database and run a macro, then close the remote database
    With app
        'Syntax: .OpenCurrentDatabase(filepath, Exclusive, strPassword) - the last 2 items are optional
        strPath = "C:\Programs\MendipDataSystems\JATFA\JATFA.accdb" 'replace with your file path
        .OpenCurrentDatabase strPath, True, "password"
    
    '    .DoCmd.RunMacro "mcrRefreshPersTable" 'run your macro
        .CloseCurrentDatabase 'closes external database as that is current
    End With
    
    'Quit the spawned app
    app.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    Set app = Nothing
    
    'Quit the current app - optional
    Application.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    
End Function
```

Above code works fine in full Access but gives error for those users who are using Access runtime version. The line of code that gives error is `Set App = New Access.Application`.

How can I fix it OR is there any alternative method to get the purpose done?

Purpose is to open the password encrypted database in separate window in Access runtime version without entering the password manually.

Best Regards

Comment: `Set App = New Access.Application` requires an install of full Access app. If you don't want to require user to enter password then why bother with password protection to begin with?

Comment: My database is split into FE and BE. BE is password encrypted too but that password can be viewed very easily by opening FE with Hex editor as password is stored as plain text in the connect string. To protect that. FE has to ne encrypted too. In this way, BE password can be protected. Whole purpose is to protect the  BE.